# Format number of an input

Tags: javascript, formatting, number-formatting

I have a system that calculates the average of fields, and then runs the javascript below , only the result comes out so 0.222048 and the correct would be 222,048 , making this conversion?

```
<script>
     function calcularMediam3etes() {
        var m1 = document.forms['formMediasETEs']['mediaQ_lsE'].value;
        var mqm3 = (m1 * 86.400)/1000;
        document.forms['formMediasETEs']['mediaQm3E'].value = mqm3;
    }
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Remove the `/1000`?

Comment: `(2.57*86.400)/1000=0.222048` `(2.57*86.400)*1000=222048`

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with formatting either.  It is really a simple math question with extraneous stuff wrapped around it.

Comment: The problem is that the calculation has to be divided by one thousand , the formula is N * 86400 / 1000. With this calculation we discover the daily flow per meter cubic , there can take .

I will test the solution of @Austin

Thank you in advance to all !

Comment: @Austin The value is to correct, but separated by decimal and the final report that makes a difference .
Any idea? Does anyone have any tips on how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed`?